# Why Gemfile for a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is Gemfile for [rspec-expectations](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/Gemfile).

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gemspec

%w[rspec rspec-core rspec-expectations rspec-mocks].each do |lib|
  library_path = File.expand_path("../../#{lib}", __FILE__)
  if File.exist?(library_path)
    gem lib, :path => library_path
  else
    gem lib, :git => "git://github.com/rspec/#{lib}.git"
  end
end

### deps for rdoc.info
gem 'yard',          '0.8.0', :require => false
gem 'redcarpet',     '2.1.1'
gem 'github-markup', '0.7.2'

platforms :jruby do
  gem "jruby-openssl"
end

eval File.read('Gemfile-custom') if File.exist?('Gemfile-custom')
```

[This is .gemspec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/rspec-expectations.gemspec)

As you can see .gemspec defines only a single dependency on `diff-lcs`. This is further [validated by rubygems page](http://rubygems.org/gems/rspec-expectations/versions/2.10.0).

My question is what is the use of Gemfile. I know bundler uses it. But for what ?

Comment: @DaveNewton as I mentioned rubygems page show that Gemfile dependencies did not declared as dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The Gemfile is for development dependencies for rspec contributors. It does not ship with the gem, but it grabs the gemspec deps so we don't have to repeat the deps in the Gemfile. Make sense?

Comment: Ah. The keyword here is for "development dependencies". So all production (read runtime ) dependencies go to .gemspec.

David: Lets say that during development I am running tests. I looked at spec_helper but I do not see any call to Bundler. So how and where exactly Gemfile is helping you do the development on rspec-expecations. Or is it that since rspec-expectations is part of larger ecosystem called (rspec) Gemfile depends on "rspec rspec-core rspec-expectations rspec-mocks". 

Thanks for all your work on rspec.